# Logic in C++ Inequality. If Else Statement

Tags: c++, if-statement, math, logic, inequality

I am trying to generate the following 2D step function in C++.

U is a function of X and Y. X goes from 0 to 2.  Y goes from 0 to 2

```
  U(x,y) =2 for 0.5<= x <= 1 and 0.5<=y<=1
  U(x,y) = 1 for everywhere else
```

Basically, it is a 2 by 2 square with a smaller square in the range (0.5<=x<=1; 0.5<=y<=1) pop out.
This is what I have: (Nx, Ny are Number of Points in X, Y respectively). 
(Y, and X are spatial coordinates)

```
for (int j = 0; j<=ny; j++){
        y[j] = j*dy;
        for (int i = 0; i <=nx;i++){
            x[i] = i*dx;
            if(x[i]>=0.5 && x[i]<=1 && y[j]>=0.5 && y[j] <=1){
                u0[j][i] = 2.0;
            }
            else{
                u0[j][i] = 1.0;
            }
        }           
    }
```

Clearly, this is not correct because this is what I got, after plotting
[2d step function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzwyI.png)

I expect my If statement to be incorrect.  Could anyone please help me?

Thank you very much.

UPDATE:  Sorry about the confusion.  X and Y are just counter for the coordinates.  Below is the code (up until what I need to ask) so hopefully all variables are there. I should have done this in the beginning.  Sorry

```
//Declaring variables

    int nx = 5; //x steps
    int ny = 5; // y steps
    int nt = 10; //time steps   
    int c = 1; //constant
    double dx = 2/double(nx-1);
    double dy = 2/double(ny-1);
    double sigma = 0.2;
    double dt = sigma*dx;
    double x[nx], y[ny]; //spatial vectors X and Y
    double u[ny][nx]; //solution matrix
    double u0[ny][nx]; //initial matrix

    //Setting up initial conditions

    for (int j = 0; j<=ny; j++){
        y[j] = j*dy;
        for (int i = 0; i <=nx;i++){
            x[i] = i*dx;
            if((x[i]>=0.5 && x[i]<=1) && (y[j]>=0.5 && y[j] <=1)){
                u0[j][i] = 2.0;
            }
            else{
                u0[j][i] = 1.0;
            }
        }           
    }
```

A lot of the variables declared are used later so I am not pasting the entire program on here. The variables of interest are X, Y,Nx, Ny, Dx, Dy, and U0.  All defined variables (Nx, Ny, Dx, Dy) are correctly defined and there are no problems (like integer with decimal places).

Comment: Why are `x` and `y` arrays (?) and not numbers like in the original specification? What are `i` and `j`?

Comment: Are you sure there is no mistake with the definitions of dx, dy, Nx, Ny ? Or even with the plotting ? I don't see any mistake in your code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is due to taking a too large step for dx and dy (0.5 each). In your plotting each "pixel" is evaluated according to its left and bottom extremes.

Consider when `i = 2` and `j = 2`, your `if` will succeed with `x[i] = 1` and `y[i] = 1`. What you should do is leave your intervals "open" on their right-sides:

```
 if((x[i]>=0.5 && x[i] < 1) && (y[j]>=0.5 && y[j] < 1)) {
 //                   ^^^                        ^^^
```

But even then, dur to floating-point arithmetic imprecision you might encouter very special cases where a pixel is drawn not as intended. that's why you should use smaller `dx` and `dy`, or equivalently bigger `nx` and `ny`.

Another issue in your code, which is not the source of this anomaly but surely needs to be corrected, you are accessing the arrays out of bounds. To avoid this:

```
for (int j = 0; j < ny; j++) {  // <-- not <=
// ...           ^^^
    for (int i = 0; i < nx; i++) {   // <-- not <=
    //               ^^^
```